# IP адрес клиента в websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, безопасность, websocket, ip

Есть простой серверный и не менее простой клиентский скрипты. Суть в том, что я хочу получать IP-адрес клиента при подключении к ws-серверу. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wsServer = new WebSocket.Server({
    port: 3001
});

var clients = new Set();

wsServer.on('connection', async ws => {
    //some code
});
```

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3001');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, что отвечает сам ws)):

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
  const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
});
```

Когда ваш сервер стоит за NGINX и подобными прокси-серверами стандартом де-факто является запись в заголовок X-Forwarded-For:

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
  const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(/\s*,\s*/)[0];
});
```

[ws: a Node.js WebSocket library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#faq)